# Top 9 Distinct records after using sub query for cumulative sum

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, gridview

I have SQL data table with following data structure

```
ID  Hrly    Hshed   Dust_removal_to_done    Dust_removal_done   Update_datetime
2   ER       MGS              4                     4             2009-05-05
3   ER       AQ               4                     2             2009-05-05
4   SR       ANDA             4                     4             2009-05-05
5   ECR      HOME             5                     5             2009-05-05
6   NR       GZB              5                     5             2009-05-05
7   NR       LDH              5                     5             2009-05-05
8   NCR      JHS              5                     5             2009-05-05
9   NCR      CNB              5                     5             2009-06-05
10  SCR      LGD              5                     5             2009-06-05
11  SCR      LGD              5                     5             2009-05-05
```

the data is fed by users on daily basis.

Further I am using a stored procedure for cumulative sum of 'Dust_removal_done' as

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[RAP_regular] as

  SELECT Hshed, HRly, Dust_removal_to_done, Dust_removal_done, (SELECT SUM(Dust_removal_done) FROM TPHRAP_regular t2 
   where t2.Hshed = TPHRAP_regular.Hshed and t2.Update_datetime <= TPHRAP_regular.Update_datetime) as cumulative_dust_removal

   FROM TPHRAP_regular
```

This stored procedure is giving me result as under

```
Hshed       Hrly        Dust_removal_to_done    Dust_removal_done       cumulative_dust_removal 
 MGS        ER                     4                   4                    4
 AQ         ER                     4                   2                    2
 ANDA       SR                     4                   4                    4
 HOME       ECR                    5                   5                    5
 GZB        NR                     5                   5                    5
 LDH        NR                     5                   5                    5
 JHS        NCR                    5                   5                    5
 CNB        NCR                    5                   5                    5
 LGD        SCR                    5                   5                   10
 LGD        SCR                    5                   5                    5
```

This is working fine. Now the issue is that there are only 9 Hsheds and therefore I want to display only 9 latest records (unique Hshed along with cumulative column) in my grid view as final result so that no Hshed will repeate in the table.  How to achieve this? please help.

Comment: Why don't you use the SUM with a group by (without the subquery)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your stored procedure(Has to be in it since you are discarding the date field in it).

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to filter only the latest records, like this:

```
SELECT Hshed,HRly,Dust_removal_to_done,Dust_removal_done,cumulative_dust_removal 
FROM(
      SELECT Hshed, HRly, Dust_removal_to_done, Dust_removal_done,
             (SELECT SUM(Dust_removal_done) FROM TPHRAP_regular t2 
              where t2.Hshed = TPHRAP_regular.Hshed 
               and t2.Update_datetime <= TPHRAP_regular.Update_datetime) as cumulative_dust_removal,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Hshed ORDER BY Update_datetime DESC) as rnk

      FROM TPHRAP_regular)
WHERE rnk = 1
```

**EDIT:** You should also use `SUM() OVER(..)` for cumulative sum , no need to select from the table twice:

```
SELECT t.Hshed,
       t.HRly,
       t.Dust_removal_to_done,
       t.Dust_removal_done,
       t.cumulative_dust_removal
  FROM (SELECT Hshed,
               HRly,
               Dust_removal_to_done,
               Dust_removal_done,
               SUM(Dust_removal_done) OVER(PARTITION BY Hshed ORDER BY Update_datetime) as cumulative_dust_removal,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Hshed ORDER BY Update_datetime DESC) as rnk
          FROM TPHRAP_regular) t
 WHERE t.rnk = 1
```

Comment: Thanx for valuable help but this is giving an error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'."

Comment: @user1185088 Updated the answer, also changed your correlated query.

Comment: Sir, since i am using SQL server 2008, 'The Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW) features are not enabled' and hence solution is not working for me even it may work in SQL server 2012..

Comment: @user1185088 `ROW_NUMBER()` works with that version, use my second query but just replace the `SUM() OVER()` with your correlated query, it should work.

Comment: Lots of thanks sir. First solution is working for me by inserting 't'  after FROM TPHRAP_regular).